# Модели не файловых источников данных

Tags: ооп, c++

Цель задачи такова: абстрагировать компонент, интенсивно работающий с файловой системой, от способа организации самой файловой системы. Т.е. клиент будет передавать компоненту реализацию некоторого абстрактного "файлового" сервиса, с которым можно выполнять типичные для файловой структуры операции: поиск элемента, чтение/запись, и пр., но при этом не должны нигде в интерфейсе фигурировать пути к конечным файлам.

Первое, что приходит на ум - это древовидная модель потоков чтения-записи, в которой сущности "каталог", "файл" - это потоки со своими методами (паттерн Компоновщик).

Какие можете подсказать другие модели для решения подобной задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу предложить вам использовать представление, схожее с тем, которое используется в некоторых системах контроля версий *(в упрощенном варианте).*

- Смысл в том, что вся древовидная структура каталогов и файлов распрямляется в *список узлов с метаданными.* Такое представление **не требует введения отношения порядка** для узлов и неплохо реализуется с помощью [`unordered` структур данных.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/unordered.html)
- А дальше все допустимые операций зависят от используемого формата и полноты метаданных. Хотите поиск по `keywords` - добавляйте их в мету и индексируйте в своем контейнере.

> Неплохой идеей выглядит использование [`digest'ов`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) типа `cd91df746a82` для идентификации узлов, поскольку вы всегда можете построить биекцию (ну, то есть, "почти биекцию") из произвольного множества на множество `digest'ов`.

- Теперь доведите этот концепт до состояния, когда у вас будет продуманное описание абстрактных узлов с метаданными и вам будет понятна семантика предполагаемых операций с этими узлами.
- Как только это сделано, можно переходить к практической реализации предлагаемого провайдера данных.

> - Предлагаю вам абстрагировать операции с узлами, применяя, например, [`boost::iostreams`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html)
> - Идея с потоками легко обобщается на любой возможный случай в силу универсальность концепта *потока* вообще, так, например, для хранения реальных данных можно использовать один большой `memory-mapped` файл, или, например, сложную иерархическую систему каталогов. При необходимости (или по желанию) вы можете добавить реалтайм `gzip` сжатие, шифрование и т.п.
> - Поскольку про `boost::iostreams::stream` известно, что он *"derives from `std::basic_istream`, `std::basic_ostream` or `std::basic_iostream`"*, то можете предоставлять вашим пользователям именно эти интерфейсы для работы с узлами.

- Сразу оговорюсь, что такую систему **непросто тестировать.** Неплохой `test suite` в этом случае должен можно спроектировать следующим образом:

> - Набор `"contract-verifying"` тестов, который прогоняется для всех реализованных провайдеров, а это тесты типа *если я добавил узел, то он должен существовать*.
> - Тесты для отдельных частей каждого из провайдеров, например, тесты на корректность `gzip` сжатия *(такие, разумеется, уже есть в тестах `boost::iostreams`, но сойдет как пример :)* Понятно, что качество и, вообще говоря, возможность тестирования напрямую зависят от связности при реализации этого провайдера.
> - `Integration` тесты, в которых поведение проверяется сразу на нескольких уровнях абстракций. *Пример* - пусть некоторый провайдер реализован таким образом, что он записывает данные узлов последовательно в один большой файл на диске. Тогда один из возможных `integration` тестов может создавать несколько узлов подряд, каждый раз проверяя, что размер реального файла на диске увеличился.

Comment: Интересно, с какой скоростью это будет работать в многопользовательской среде.

А также хотелось бы увидеть набросок программы, показывающей, что в такой системе программировать **удобнее**, чем в традиционной posix.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ! Пожалуй, идея с unordered-контейнером в качестве абстракции структуры файловой системы - лучший вариант. После первой тестовой реализации напишу о результатах.

Comment: @avp, в моем случае проблем с многопользовательским сценарием возникнуть не должно, т.к. с одной "веткой" реальной файловой системы в один момент времени будет работать только один клиент.

Удобство в следующем: важно контролировать все операции чтения/записи файлов разными под-системами одного большого приложения, а именно в случае, когда часть данных расположены локально, а часть находятся на некотором сетевом ресурсе (что-то вроде разделяемого файлового сервера). Т.е. изолировать под-системы от знания о местоположении файлов и способе их хранения.

Comment: @vladimir_ki, что значит контролировать ?

Если у Вас просто задача чтения-записи файлов, часть из которых локальна, а часть на северах в LAN, то можно подумать над локальным деревом, NFS, символьными линками и automount. 

Или ZFS. Или LustreFS. Или каком-нибудь их легковесном аналоге.

Приложение будет видеть (если глубоко не полезет в детали доступа) единообразную иерархию.

Вообще-то немного странно, что Вы не закладываетесь на возможность одновременного доступа от нескольких клиентов.

Comment: @avp, необходимость контроля вызвана еще и тем, что с помощью такой "файловой" системы будет организовано нечто вроде VCS, только в весьма специфичной области - электронной картографии. 

Эти продукты выпускаются в совершенно невероятных конфигурациях, а использование одного из перечисленных вариантов FS, как абстрактного слоя а не реализации, с одной стороны будет избыточно, а с другой - наложит архитектурные особенности самой FS, а также лишит возможности непосредственно "влезать" в процесс там, где это нужно.